# Have a commande with the "CanXXXX" listening to multiple properties

Tags: wpf, xaml, command

I'm in the process of doing an `UserControl` that can display a Wizard(With WPF+Prism).

In order to do so, I've two controls: `Wizard` and `WizardPage`.

I wish I can end with such things

```
<Wizard>
    <WizardPage CanGoToNext="{Binding SomePropertySayingThatThisPaneIsOk}">
        <TextBlock>Page one</TextBlock>
    </WizardPage>
    <WizardPage CanGoToNext="{Binding SomePropertySayingThatThisPaneIsOk}" CanGoToPrevious="False">
        <TextBlock>Page Four</TextBlock>
    </WizardPage>
    <WizardPage CanGoToNext="{Binding SomePropertySayingThatThisPaneIsOk}" CanGoToPrevious="True">
        <TextBlock>Page Three</TextBlock>
    </WizardPage>
</Wizard>
```

I'm currently stuck on the command within the Wizard UserControl.

I will have 3 `Buttons`:

- Previous
- Next
- Cancel

On which I would like to bind some commands of the UserControl.

The issue is the condition to update if a button's command can be executed.

In my case I would like:

```
//PseudoCode
CurrentPage != FirstPage
&& CurrentPage.CanGoToPrevious
```

But I don't see how to make a `DelegateCommand` and ask them to check again its condition when the dependency property of the `CurrentPage.CanGoToPrevious` change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, usually in WPF people use CommandManager.RequerySuggested event and CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested method when they want to force some control to refresh it's command CanExecuted. However I don't like that and never do that, because it's very inefficient (so I won't get into details about that). So, best approach to my mind is this:

```
public class DelegateCommand : ICommand {
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;
    private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

    public DelegateCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute) {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) {
        return _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter) {
        _execute(parameter);
    }

    public void RefreshCanExecute() {
        var handler = CanExecuteChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
}
```

Then when something has changed, just call DelegateCommand.RefreshCanExecute:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window {
    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BtnCommand = new DelegateCommand(_ => {
            MessageBox.Show("test");
        }, _ => CheckCanExecute());
        this.DataContext = this;            
    }

    private bool CheckCanExecute() {
        return SomeProperty == 1;
    }

    public int SomeProperty
    {
        get { return (int) GetValue(SomePropertyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SomePropertyProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SomePropertyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SomeProperty", typeof(int), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(0, OnSomePropertyChanged));

    private static void OnSomePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
        ((MainWindow) d).BtnCommand.RefreshCanExecute();
    }

    public DelegateCommand BtnCommand { get; private set; }      
}
```

Xaml:

```
<Button Content="test" Command="{Binding BtnCommand}" />
```

EDIT to response to comment. Sure you can bind to multiple properies, it's just have nothing to do with commands, so I didn't realize you are interested in this. You can do it like this - first create multi value converter:

```
public class AndConverter : IMultiValueConverter {
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        if (values.Length == 0) return false;
        return values.All(c => c != null && c != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue && (bool) c);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Which accepts multiple boolean values (nulls are treated as false) and evaluates and over them. Now in xaml just bind IsEnabled of button to your model properties:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <wpf:AndConverter x:Key="and" />
</Window.Resources>
<Button Content="test" Command="{Binding BtnCommand}">
    <Button.IsEnabled>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource and}">
            <Binding Path="IsFirstPage" />
            <Binding Path="CanGoToPrevious" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </Button.IsEnabled>
</Button>
```

Now on any of bound properties change, your converter will be reevaluated and IsEnabled property of button refreshed.

Comment: Ok. So the response is "no", there is no way to listen multiple properties. I know doing one method which retrieve the values of all the items, but since one of my item is a dependency property, I thought that it was possible to indicate that the command availability may change when the DP change.